# PHP Limitar letras no resultado

Tags: php

Como faço para limitar a quantidade de letras que irão aparecer em `<?= $v['titulo']?>` dentro da `<div class="col-md-4 panel">`

Já tentei várias coisas, mas só dá erro.

```
<?php $result = selectAllAnuncios(1,18); foreach ($result as $k => $v):
    $link = "anuncio,".$v['id'].",".str_replace(" ","-",$v['titulo'])."-".str_replace(" ","-",$v['ano']);
    $image  = (@is_file("img/anuncios/".$v["imgs"][0]["name"])) ? "img/anuncios/".$v["imgs"][0]["name"] : "img/no-img.jpg" ; ?>

    <div class="col-md-4 panel ">
        <a href="<?=$link?>"> <img src='<?=$image?>' width="200" height="100">
        <div ><?=$v['titulo'] ?> </br> <?=$v['ano']?> - R$ <?=$v['preco']?>   
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Você tentou o substr?

Comment: Quais seriam estes erros? `Exceptions` ou não limita os caracteres? ...

Comment: Você quer que apareça então tipo: titulo aqui va...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você for limitar os caracteres, você pode usar o `substr` do PHP mesmo.
Da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php $result = selectAllAnuncios(1,18); foreach ($result as $k => $v):
    $link = "anuncio,".$v['id'].",".str_replace(" ","-",$v['titulo'])."-".str_replace(" ","-",$v['ano']);
    $image  = (@is_file("img/anuncios/".$v["imgs"][0]["name"])) ? "img/anuncios/".$v["imgs"][0]["name"] : "img/no-img.jpg" ; ?>

    <div class="col-md-4 panel ">
        <a href="<?=$link?>"> <img src='<?=$image?>' width="200" height="100">
        <div ><?=substr($v['titulo'], 0, 10)."..."; ?> </br> <?=$v['ano']?> - R$ <?=$v['preco']?>   
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

> ```
> substr($v['titulo'], 0, 10)."...";
> ```

Neste caso, 0 é o ponto de inicio e 10 é a quantidade de caracteres a serem lidos.

> Referencia: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

Conforme sugerido pelo Wallace, você pode usar a função m_substr, da seguinte maneira:

```
mb_substr($v['titulo'], 0, 10,'UTF-8');
```

Repassando então o UTF-8 para que não haja problemas com caracteres especiais.

> Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou redondo aqui. Não conhecia essa função.

Comment: Beleza @LeandroBorges :) Assim que possível aceite minha resposta como correta. Note também que você pode dar uma olhada na documentação que coloquei como referência, é importante ler.

Comment: Vai ter problemas com caracteres `UTF-8` se usar `substr`. Nesse caso, é melhor usar `mb_substr` com o parâmetro `UTF-8`, para não ter problemas.

Comment: Recomendo que sempre pesquise se já existe uma resposta para o problema usando o buscador do site http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=substr%20%5bphp%5d%20is%3aanswer e ao invés de responder prefira duplicar.

Comment: Para variar, há outro problema na resposta: Qualquer texto sempre vai ter o `"..."` no final. Acho que seria interessante adicionar uma verificação para saber o tamanho da `string` antes de limitá-la e colocar a reticências

Comment: Muito válido sua argumentação @WallaceMaxters.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda pessoal.  Tirei o "..." do final, coloquei o mb_substr para UTF-8 e limitei em 22 caracteres por causa da largura da coluna. Obrigado a todos.